# Creating select option value list from an array

Tags: php, arrays, parent-child

I have an array like this (stored in the **$optDir** variable):

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 8
            [title] => Atasan Pria
            [idparent] => 5
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 5
            [title] => Fashion
            [idparent] => 0
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 7
            [title] => Motor
            [idparent] => 0
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [id] => 6
            [title] => Mobil
            [idparent] => 0
        )

    [4] => Array
        (

            [id] => 9
            [title] => Hem
            [idparent] => 8
        )

)
```

And i have PHP Codes like this :

```
function optCatAds($pos=0, $level=0){                   
        global $optDir;  $opt = "";
        $n = count($optDir);
        for($i=0;$i<$n;$i++){           
            $l = $level*3;
            $sign=""; for ($z=0;$z<=$l;$z++){$sign.="&nbsp;";}
            if($optDir[$i]['idparent']==$pos){
            $opt .= '<option value="'.$optDir[$i][id].'">'.$sign.$optDir[$i][title].'</option>';
            optCatAds($optDir[$i][id], $level + 1);
            }
        }                               
        return $opt;
    }
```

When i call the **optCatAds** function, give output like below:

```
<option value="5">Fashion</option>
<option value="6">Mobil</option>
<option value="7">Motor</option>
```

But, I want to made output like below :

```
<option value="5">Fashion</option>
<option value="8">  Atasan Pria</option>
<option value="9">    Hem</option>
<option value="6">Mobil</option>
<option value="7">Motor</option>
```

**Conditions :**

1. Fashion, Mobil, Motor <-- parent
2. **Fashion** have child Atasan **Pria**
3. **Atasan Pria** have child **Hem**

Can someone help me? Thank to your help.

Comment: this order is based on what ??You can do it manually without loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will work fine for you

```
$optDir = Array(Array("id"=>8,"title"=>"Atasan Pria","idparent"=>5),
                Array("id"=>5,"title"=>"Fashion","idparent"=>0),
                Array("id"=>7,"title"=>"Motor","idparent"=>0),
                Array("id"=>6,"title"=>"Mobil","idparent"=>0),
                Array("id"=>9,"title"=>"Hem","idparent"=>8)
                );

function optCatAds($pos=0, $level=0)
{                   
    global $optDir;$opt;
    for($i=0;$i<count($optDir);$i++)
    {           
        $l = $level*3;
        $sign="";
        for ($z=0;$z<$l;$z++){$sign.="&nbsp;";}
        if($optDir[$i]['idparent']==$pos)
        {
            $opt .= '<option value="'.$optDir[$i]['id'].'">'.$sign.$optDir[$i]['title'].'</option>';
            $opt .= optCatAds($optDir[$i]['id'], $level + 1);
        }
    }                               
    return $opt;
}

$res = optCatAds($pos=0, $level=0);
echo "<select>{$res}</select>";
```

Comment: i just added your level spaces too :)

Comment: u just forgott to add the $opt .= to your recursiv function line 12 and of course some ' in your code

Answer (score 0):

Can you try `foreach` instead of `for` loop ,

```
foreach($optDir as $k=>$value){     
    $opt .= '<option value="'.$value->id.'">'.$sign.$value->title.'</option>';      
}
```

Comment: I want the order to follow the parent-child structure

Answer (score 0):

Replace `$optDir[$i][title]` with `$optDir[$i]['title']`

and `$optDir[$i][id]` with `$optDir[$i]['id']`

Here you are making recursive call so you can not get complete

```
function optCatAds($pos=0, $level=0){                   
        global $optDir;  $opt = "";
        foreach($optDir as $each){
            if($each['id']==8) $level = 2;
            if($each['id']==9) $level = 3;
            $l = $level*3;
            $sign=""; for($z=0;$z<=$l;$z++){$sign.="&nbsp;";}
            if($each['idparent']==$pos){
                $opt .= '<option value="'.$each['id'].'">'.$sign.$each['title'].'</option>';
            }
        }                               
        return $opt;
    }
```

Comment: results remain the same.

`<option value="5">Fashion</option>
<option value="6">Mobil</option>
<option value="7">Motor</option>`

Comment: I think it's less effective, how if there are a lot of id's?

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

$optDir = Array(
    Array(
        'id' => 8,
        'title' => 'Atasan Pria',
        'idparent' => 5
    ),
    Array(
        'id' => 5,
        'title' => 'Fashion',
        'idparent' => 0
    ),
    Array(
        'id' => 7,
        'title' => 'Motor',
        'idparent' => 0
    ),
    Array(
        'id' => 6,
        'title' => 'Mobil',
        'idparent' => 0
    ),
    Array(
        'id' => 9,
        'title' => 'Hem',
        'idparent' => 8
    )
);

function getOptionsRecursive($idParent = 0, $spaces = '') {
    global $optDir;
    $s = '';
    for($i = 0 ; $i < sizeof($optDir) ; $i++) {
        $current = $optDir[$i];
        if($current['idparent'] == $idParent) {
            $s .= '<option value="'.$current['id'].'">'.$spaces.$current['title'].'</option>';
            $s .= getOptionsRecursive($current['id'], $spaces.' ');
        }
    }
    return $s;
};

echo getOptionsRecursive();

?>
```